# How can i access one model data from another and viceversa with reverse relationship

Tags: python, django

[api for catalogs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyQSN.png)

here is my models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    company_name = models.ForeignKey('Company',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Catalog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    no_of_pcs = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    per_piece_price = models.DecimalField(null=True,blank=True,max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
    company_name = models.ForeignKey(Company,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

here is my seralizers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *
from django.db.models import Sum,Avg,Max,Min,Count,F,Q

class CatalogSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    dynamic_data = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Catalog
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_dynamic_data(self, obj):
        totalpieces = Catalog.objects.all().aggregate(total_pieces=Count('no_of_pcs'))
        totalprice = Catalog.objects.all().aggregate(total_price=Sum('per_piece_price'))
        return totalprice,totalpieces

class CompanySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = '__all__'

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    company_name = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

here is my view.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import *
import json
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponse

from .serializers import *
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework import viewsets


class CatalogView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset =  Catalog.objects.select_related('company_name')
    serializer_class = CatalogSerializer

class CompanyView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset =  Company.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer

class UserView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset =  User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

here is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

from api import views
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('catalogs',views.CatalogView)
router.register('companies',views.CompanyView)
router.register('users',views.UserView)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include(router.urls)),
]
```

when i will go
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/companies/`

m expecting

```
 [
    {
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/companies/1/",
        "name": "google",
        "phone_number": 123214214,
        "catalog_details":[
             "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalogs/1/",
            "name": "sobhagya",
            "no_of_pcs": 22,
            "per_piece_price": "3567.00",
        ]
    }
]
```

Here i am able to access company name in catalog but, how can access i access all catalog details in company

please refer the screen shot
 i wants to access catalog details from company the way m abl to access company name in catalog api.

thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the company serializer, explicitly add all the field from the Company class including the catalogue's reverse relation.

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('name', 'phone_number', 'catalog_set')
```

Even better, add a related name in the Catalog class

```
class Catalog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    no_of_pcs = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    per_piece_price = models.DecimalField(null=True,blank=True,max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
    company_name = models.ForeignKey(Company,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='catalog')
```

and then change the field name from catalog_set to catalog in the company serializer's fields.

If you want to restrict or modify the catalog data that you want to show in the company serializer, you can define the catalogue serializer this way

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    catalog = CatalogSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('name', 'phone_number', 'catalog')
```